# Can't use require in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to import local images in my react native app, by using the "require" keyword, but everytime I use require I get a 500 response code from the development server.

```
<Image key={value + "1"} source={require("./giantdoubble.png")} style={{height: 100, width: 100}}/>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert(value)} key={value} style={styles.card} >
   <Text>xD</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Can you provide a little bit of code. Maybe you are pointing at the wrong path: <Image source={require('../../Path')} /> ?

Comment: The compiler says  that the file doesn't exist, but the path isn't incorrect. The PNG is litteraly in the same folder as the file

Answer (score 1):

For some reason my PNG file used PNG with all caps, which made it unrecognizable by the code. Converting it to a png with lower case characters resolved the issue.